# passing values from node.js to python function

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, pip

I have this code in Node.js

```
let options = req.body
PythonShell.run('./chat.py', options, function (err, results) {
    console.log(results)
})
```

In my chat.py file, I have this:

```
import sys
import json

def chatFun():
    options = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    print(options)
    print(sys.argv[1])
    return

chatFun()
```

When I run my code without the `print(sys.argv[1])`, and just put `print("hello world")`, it works, but then I put `print(sys.argv[1])` and it gives me:

```
null
null
```

Not sure why this is happening. Could anyone share some advice.

value of options:

```
city: New York,
party_size: 5,
stay: hotel
```

Comment: Are you using [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell)? If so it would be good to know what the value of `options` is (the value in NodeJS).

Comment: yes, python-shell. I have updated my answer to include value of options

Comment: Just to make sure your `req.body` is valid JSON?

Comment: @Palladium02 yes, it is. I actually followed the answer from johnnyshrewd and added something in that made it work. I will post an answer shortly